# Randomly place svg polygons

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, polygon, snap.svg

I have a svg polygon and I want to replicate them n number of times dynamically.So the problem I am facing is when I replicate them how should I replicate the points.
Instead of hardcoding the points in the array I want them to be generated dynamically. Please help me

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var polyarray= {
    "polyobj": [{
      "id": 0,
      "name": 'Poly',
      "points":'20,10 30,30 30,20',
      "color":'#ed078d'
    },{
      "id": 1,
      "name": 'Poly1',
      "points":'20,50 10,50 30,60',
      "color": '#d71f39'
    },{
      "id": 2,
      "name": 'Poly2',
      "points":'60,10 70,30 80,20',
      "color":'#ed4a39'
    },{
      "id": 3,
      "name": 'Poly3',
      "points":'40,80 60,90,60,100',
      "color": '#f78d37'
    },{
      "id": 4,
      "name": 'Poly4',
      "points":'50,50 50,60 80,50',
      "color": '#c52031'
    }]
  }

  for (i = 0; i < polyarray.polyobj.length; i++) {
    var color = polyarray.polyobj[i].color;  
               
    var nowCloned = $( "#main-0" ).clone();
       
    nowCloned[0].id = "main-"+(i);
    var nc = "clip"+(i+1);

    var fnow = nowCloned.find('polygon')
      fnow.attr("id",nc);
      fnow.css({"fill":color});
      fnow.attr("points",polyarray.polyobj[i].points);    

    nowCloned.appendTo( "#Layer_1" );           
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="Layer_1" class="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 324.61 150.83">
  <g id="main-0" style="position:absolute; top:-899px;">
    <polygon points="" id="poly" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please include jQuery in the code snippet

Comment: If its just for display and shapes will be the same, but just position random, you could clone the same one and transform randomly.

Answer (score 2):

You could store your polygons to be cloned in a defs element. Each cloned element can be located at the point you desire by using the bounding box and translate attribute.
See the example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Replicate Polygons</title>
</head>

<body onload=placePolys()>
<svg id=mySVG width=500 height=500>
<defs id=myClones>
    <polygon id="poly1" points="20,50 10,50 30,60" fill="#ed078d" />
    <polygon id="poly2"  points="60,10 70,30 80,20" fill="#d71f39" />
    <polygon id="poly3"  points="40,80 60,90,60,100" fill="#f78d37" />
    <polygon id="poly4" points="50,50 50,60 80,50" fill="#c52031" />
</defs>
</svg>


</body>
<script>
var locArray=[]
locArray[0]=["poly2",120,60]
locArray[1]=["poly2",60,50]
locArray[2]=["poly3",200,90]
locArray[3]=["poly4",320,340]
locArray[4]=["poly1",400,100]
locArray[5]=["poly3",100,120]
locArray[6]=["poly1",440,50]
locArray[7]=["poly4",120,300]
locArray[8]=["poly4",440,440]
locArray[9]=["poly3",100,300]
locArray[10]=["poly3",450,300]

function placePolys()
{
    for(var k=0;k<locArray.length;k++)
    {
        var loc=locArray[k]
        var cloneMe=loc[0]
        var clone=document.getElementById(cloneMe).cloneNode(true)
        clone.setAttribute("id","clone"+k)
        var x=loc[1]
        var y=loc[2]
        mySVG.appendChild(clone)
        var bb=clone.getBBox()
        var bbx=bb.x
        var bby=bb.y
        var bbw=bb.width
        var bbh=bb.height
        var cx=bbx+.5*bbw
        var cy=bby+.5*bbh
        var transX=x-cx
        var transY=y-cy
        clone.setAttribute("transform","translate("+transX+" "+transY+")")
    }
}

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
  function createNewPolyPoint(offset) {
                var pageHeight = $(window).height() - offset,
                    pageWidth = $(window).width() - offset,
                    randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * pageHeight),
                    randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * pageWidth);
                return [randomX, randomY];
            }
```

You can get 3 sets of random points for every poly you want to draw, afterwards add them to your poly array structure before appending.